# javascript collection validation not working with Struts 2 tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, struts2

I am iterating a list in jsp file using struts 2  tag as follows.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<head>
<s:head theme="ajax" debug="true" />
<script type="text/javascript">
function add(x) {
    document.insertForm.action="load.action?mode=add&index="+x;
    document.insertForm.submit();
}

function del(x) {
    document.insertForm.action="load.action?mode=delete&index="+x;
    document.insertForm.submit();
}

function copy(x) {
    document.insertForm.action="load.action?mode=copy&index="+x;
    document.insertForm.submit();
}

function validateDate(date) {
    for(var i=0; i<date.length; i++) {
         var x = date[i].value;
         if(x == null || x == "") { 
             alert("please enter the date");
             date[i].focus();
             return false;
         }
    }
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <s:form action="insert" name="insertForm">
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <th>CHANNEL_ID</th>
                <th>TASK</th>
                <th>DATE</th>
                <th>HOURS</th>
            </tr> 

            <s:iterator value="timeTrackerRecords" status="stat">
                <tr>
                    <td align="center"><s:select name="timeTrackerRecords[%{#stat.index}].channel_Id"
                            list="channelList" value="%{channel_Id}" theme="simple"
                            cssStyle="width:90px;">
                        </s:select></td>

                    <td align="center"><s:select name="timeTrackerRecords[%{#stat.index}].task" list="taskList"
                            value="%{task}" theme="simple" cssStyle="width:90px;">
                        </s:select></td>

                    <td><s:datetimepicker name="timeTrackerRecords[%{#stat.index}].date"
                            value="%{date}" displayFormat="yyyy-MM-dd" theme="simple" />
                    </td>

                    <td align="center"><s:textfield name="timeTrackerRecords[%{#stat.index}].hours" theme="simple" 
                            value="%{hours}" cssStyle="width:90px;" ></s:textfield></td>

                    <td>
                        <input type="submit" value="Add" onclick="add('<s:property value="%{#stat.index}"  />')" />
                    </td>               
                    <td>    
                       <input type="submit" value="Del" onclick="del('<s:property value="%{#stat.index}"  />')" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="submit" value="Copy" onclick="copy('<s:property value="%{#stat.index}"  />')" />
                    </td>

                </tr>
            </s:iterator>
        </table>

         <br>
         <s:submit value="Insert" align="left" onclick="return validateDate(document.insertForm.date)"/>
    </s:form>
</body>
```

date validation **is not working** with below line of code. **Inside the validateDate(date) function date is coming undefined.**

```
<td><s:datetimepicker name="timeTrackerRecords[%{#stat.index}].date"
                            value="%{date}" displayFormat="yyyy-MM-dd" theme="simple" />
                    </td>
```

date validation **is working** with below line of code.

```
<td>
<s:datetimepicker name="date" value="%{date}" displayFormat="yyyy-MM-dd" theme="simple" />
</td>
```

The only difference is declaring date field as follows.

```
name="date"
name="timeTrackerRecords[%{#stat.index}].date" (is used to pass the form data(date) to action class)
```

Requesting you to please help me on this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of a validator to you use?

Comment: Doing simply null check inside validateDate(date) function. Whether the date is null or not. If null then showing prompt message to enter the date.

Comment: I guess you're using an old version of struts2, there's no datetimepicker tag. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

While changing the name of the date-picker, you don't change the parameter being passed to the validate function

`onclick="return validateDate(document.insertForm.date)"`

Just change this appropriately, according to the name of the datepicker.

*Solution 2*

Another good style, is to give the date-picker an id and use that id in the validate function to retrieve the value of it, something like

`document.getElementById('mydate').value;` for datepicker :

```
<s:datetimepicker id="mydate" ...>
```

and hence, the function can change to

```
function validateDate() {
    var date=document.getElementById('mydate').value;
    alert(date);
    for(var i=0; i<date.length; i++) {
         var x = date[i].value;
         if(x == null || x == "") { 
             alert("please enter the date");
             date[i].focus();
             return false;
         }
    }
}
```

**Update Solution 3**

Since we are having multiple elements and the validation should work on all of them, so we have to put up a class for identifying those elements and then see if any of those is empty or null. For this we have to include jquery.

```
<head>
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/latest.js"/>
</head>


<s:datetimepicker class="validate-date" .../>
<s:submit onclick="return validate()" .../>


<script>
function validate(){
    var success=true;
    $(".validate-date").each(function(element){
         var x = element.val();
         if(x == null || x == "") { 
             alert("please enter the date");
             date[i].focus();
             success=false;
             break;
         }
    });
    return success;
}
</script>
```

The above code is UN-TESTED, but I'm sure something like that will work fine.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As per your soulution 2 date is still coming undefined using below syntax.                                       var date=document.getElementById('mydate').value;                     As mentioned not passing any parmaeter  to validateDate() function.Please help me on this. Also not able to understand soultion 1 suggested.

Comment: for solution 2, have you changed the id of the element ?

Comment: Yes i have change the id of the element.  Current date line code is ,      <td><s:datetimepicker id="mydate" name="timeTrackerRecords[%{#stat.index}].date" value="%{date}"  displayFormat="yyyy-MM-dd" theme="simple" /> </td>

Comment: It's within an iterator and there-fore there must be multiple elements with the same id and hence, it might not be working.

Comment: Thanks for your reply :) Can you please provide any alternate solution.

Comment: I have tried suggested solution 3 but <s:datetimepicker.. /> has no class attribute. Please check the below link for the datetimepicker attribute. http://struts.apache.org/release/2.0.x/docs/datetimepicker.html

Comment: `cssClass` - sorry, about that.

Comment: Currently I have used struts2-core-2.0.11.jar in which datetimepicker is available. But in struts2-core-2.1.8.1.jar datetimepicke is not available.

Comment: it's better to stick to latest version & not use deprecated stuff. As a replacement for datetimepicker, you can use [Struts2 Jquery Plugin](https://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/). It has really cool other components too.